# Flutter widget auto-height in column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem with Column and this [Calendar widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel). It doesn't work without specifing height of calendar (whole column is invisible). But with specific height (comment in code) it's not responsive. I do not understand why "auto height" doesn't work here and I tried everything. Calendar default height is "double.infinity" and it works perfect without column or row.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Column(
    children: [
      CalendarCarousel(
        //height: 400,
      ),
      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red,)),
    ],
  )
);
```

This is what I want:
[image: app]

Comment: Just wrap with Expanded widget it's working

Comment: Expanded(
                      child: CalendarCarousel(
                      ),
                    ),

Comment: Well not really... It just split screen to half but you have to scroll in calendar. I want to show whole calendar and then fill rest of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I discovered differend [calendar custom widget](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) and it works perfectly without specifying height.

Answer (score 0):

Wiget in a Flex (i.e Column, Row) must have a bounded size in the direction of its flex parent's main axis.

I have not ever used this package. Wrap your `CalendarCarousel` with a `AspectRadio` or a `Flexible` with `fit: FlexFit.loose` may be helpful.

If this doesn't help, then i recommond you to read the source code of this package, which won't be much pain in my opinion. :)

Comment: I've tried fit: FlexFit.loose before. I will try to read the source. Thanks.